# Authentication with Google without redirect instead of popup

Tags: html, authentication, google-signin

I created an Google login button:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Google Auth Demo</title>
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com">
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  <script>
    function signOut() {
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signOut().then(function() {
      console.log('user signed out')
    })};
    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
      console.log(googleUser.getBasicProfile());
    } 
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to the Demo</h1>
  <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-ux_mode="redirect" ></div>
  <button onclick="signOut()" >Sign out</button>
</body>
</html>
```

I changed a param from popup to `data-ux_mode="redirect"`. How do I configure the field `Authorized redirect URIs` or change somethingelse for my app on https://console.developer.google so I can use it on localhost?

I had find a close issues here: https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/288#issuecomment-289064472 . So it's availabe for implement code authen button Google sample without open popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add authorized domains and redirect URI's to your client ID or API keys using this URL

https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project={YOUR-GOOGLE-CLOUD-PROJECT-NAME}

Basically in the GCP console, on the left navigation bar go to APIs and Services. Over there look for the oAuth2.0 client ID you are using in your project. Once you click on it you have an interface to configure Authorized redirect URIs and Authorized JavaScript origins

Edit: upon going through the linked github issue(which is still open by the way) it is not possible to get the token to a local machine using the redirect UX. They have plans to support it in the future but currently only works with popup method.

> Hi @Jeevsxp, this is not possible to obtain an authorization code
>   without popup. This is a security restriction: an offline code will
>   allow you to obtain a refresh_token in the server, that gives you the
>   possibility to obtain a fresh access_token anytime you want. For that,
>   the user needs explicit consent

Comment: Also as a clarification, the google sign in page will redirect automatically to the page that is calling it. That is to say that when you call the google sign in page from localhost:3000 you will be redirected to localhost:3000 from the google sign in page after authentication. But google will not do this by default for all URLs. It will check if the URL from where the request is originating from (localhost:3000 in this case) is present in the authorised javascript origins. If not it will not even entertain the request.

Comment: ^^ Yup bro, I had find anymore way to implement that. Issues closed in my question input link. I also think can't config without open popup. Let's wait implement of they.